# "Missing a using directive or assembly reference?" error when trying to publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, ef-core-3.1

I had a perfectly working application that uses AspNetCore Identity for authentication. I needed every User to be part of the Organization entity, so I added this relationship to my model (and configured via Fluent API):

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{  
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
}

public class Organization : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
    public OrganizationType Type { get; set; }
}
```

For manipulation with Organizations, I created IOrganizationService interface and OrgnizationService class that implements it, injecting it exactly the same way I am injecting other services (and repository)

```
public static void ConfigureOrganizationService(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IOrganizationService, OrganizationService>();
}
```

My problem is that I am getting these two errors when trying to publish the application:

```
The type or namespace name 'Organizations' does not exist in the namespace 'Apm.Application.Services' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  ApmBackend  C:\Users\Karel Křesťan\source\repos\apm-backend\ApmBackend\Extensions\ServiceExtensions.cs  14  

The type or namespace name 'IOrganizationService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ApmBackend  C:\Users\Karel Křesťan\source\repos\apm-backend\ApmBackend\Startup.cs   104
```

The first error is from class I am using to store extensions I am calling in Startup configuration method and it's a simple using statement

```
using Apm.Application.Services.Organizations;
```

The second error is from Configure method definition in Startup class (first line):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env, IUserService userService, IOrganizationService organizationService, IRepositoryWrapper repository)
{
    ...
}
```

There are two strange things about this error

1. It's occurring only during publish, not during building/compilling/running, and on all machines I tried it
2. I tried to rewrite the application several times to avoid using OrganizationService (on the first try, I merged it to UserService, on the second try, I merged it to OrganizationRepository) and it still failed to publish, even though the errors were slightly different, depending on what exactly I did (failed to find IUserService namespace on the first try, failed to find IOrganizationRepository on the second try). If I remove IOrganizationService from Startup and ServiceExtensions class, application publishes correctly with no problem. Sadly, I need that service in my Startup class to seed some default data, can't avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Windows Identity Foundation SDK (the Foundation itself was already present).

I then re-added the Microsoft.IdentityModel DLL and the problem seems to have gone.

Strange misleading error!!